# Connecting 4P4C RJ9 Headset to 3.5mm pc port

Tags: analog, audio, telephone, pc

I have a Plantronics CS520 Binaural headset that I'm trying to connect to my PC instead of a desk phone.

I'm using a TRRS with T connected to speaker+, R disconnected, R connected to Mic, and S being the common ground.

Audio plays great, but the mic pics up everything playing extremely loudly (and it's not that it's picking up audio from the room). I found if I place a 2k2 resistor between mic and ground it's lessened, but still not usable. Based off [This link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/373716/pc-headset-crosstalk) I suspect I'll need to find a way to stop the common ground dirtying the mic. Is there some type of capacitor/diode filter I could setup?

Comment: What's the pinout of the 4p4c headset connector and how you wired it to TRRS connector?

Comment: @Justme I guessed the pinout by trial and error, e.g. connecting just the speaker wires to the cable on the TRRS - I followed OMTP layout in connecting the 4p4c wires to the poles. The 4p4c layout appears to be slightly non-standard with both speaker wires being 1 and 2, and mic being 3 and 4. To be clear I've cut a 4p4c cable to connect to the 4p4c jack on the headset, then soldered those onto a trrs cable i cut in half.